# Tratar uma palavra com ponto

Tags: java, css

Eu possuo um método que recebe um texto como parâmetro e faz um `.split` no texto separando as palavras por `" "`. Para cada palavra no texto eu faço uma verificação checando se a palavra é igual ao item da minha lista de `Enum`, caso a a palavra seja igual ao `Enum` a palavra recebe uma formatação para css. Como eu separo as palavras por `" "` algumas palavras podem vir precedentes ou procedentes com um `.`(ponto). Eu gostaria de tratar somente a palavra ignorando o ponto e após tratar a palavra, voltar o ponto ao seu lugar, como posso fazer ? Pensei em algumas situações mas sem sucesso. Este é meu método:

```
public static String checkTipoPokemon(String texto) {
        List<TipoPokemon> lista = Arrays.asList(TipoPokemon.values());
        String palavras[] = texto.split(" ");
        String tipoIngles = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            String tipo = lista.get(i).name().toUpperCase();
            tipoIngles = tipo + "-type";
            for (String palavra : palavras) {
                if (palavra.toUpperCase().equals(tipo) || palavra.toUpperCase().equals(tipoIngles.toUpperCase())) {
                    texto = texto.replace(palavra,
                            "<span id=" + "tipo-" + tipo.toLowerCase() + ">" + palavra + "</span>");
                }
            }
        }
        return texto;
    }
```

Ex: Observe o seguinte texto:

> electic. Quando o HP está abaixo de 1/3, os moves do tipo FIRE ganham
>   um bônus de 50% grass.

Existem 3 palavras a serem formatadas: *electric*, *fire* e *grass*. Porém electric tem um ponto antes e grass tem o ponto depois. Deve se ignorar os pontos e formatar só a palavra ficando assim no final:

```
.<span id="tipo-electric">electric</span>
<span id="tipo-grass">grass</span>.
```

Dependendo da palavra, terá uma formatação diferente, mas as palavras terão formatação semelhante, ex:

```
.tipo-pokemon span {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#fire {
    color: #EE8130;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#water {
    color: #6890F0;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#ice {
    color: #98D8D8;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#electric {
    color: #F8D030;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#grass {
    color: #78C850;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#dark {
    color: #705848;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#bug {
    color: #A8B820;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#ghost {
    color: #705898;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#rock {
    color: #B8A038;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#fairy {
    color: #EE99AC;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#ground {
    color: #E2BF65;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#dragon {
    color: #7038F8;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#psychic {
    color: #F85888;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#poison {
    color: #A040A0;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#normal {
    color: #A8A878;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#fighting {
    color: #C03028;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#steel {
    color: #B8B8D0;
}

.tipo-pokemon span#flying {
    color: #A890F0;
}
```

Após sugestão do @Sorack, segue o print de como ficou meu dataTable:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O texto gerado na primeira coluna foi este:

```
<span class="tipo-pokemon <span class="tipo-pokemon grass">grass</span>"><span class="tipo-pokemon grass">grass</span></span> <span class="tipo-pokemon <span class="tipo-pokemon electric">electric</span>"><span class="tipo-pokemon electric">electric</span></span>. Quando o HP está abaixo de 1/3, os moves do tipo <span class="tipo-pokemon <span class="tipo-pokemon fire">fire</span>"><span class="tipo-pokemon fire">FIRE</span></span> ganham um bônus de 50% grass
```

Comment: Pode adicionar um exemplo dessas palavras separadas com espaço e contendo o ponto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomei a liberdade de fazer algumas correções em pontos que não foram apontados na pergunta:

- Você está utilizando `id` no elemento `span`, o que é incorreto caso você tenha mais um elemento para aplicar o `estilo`, então mudei para `class` e corrigi o `CSS` (Adicionei um `HTML` com o resultado + `CSS` no final da resposta para comprovar as correções na geração e no `CSS`);
- Alterei a palavra `electric` que estava com a grafia errada na frase de exemplo.

Criei a seguinte classe de exemplo:

```
public class Pokemon {

  public enum Tipo {
    FIRE, WATER, ICE, ELECTRIC, GRASS, DARK, BUG, GHOST, ROCK, FAIRY, GROUND, DRAGON, PSYCHIC, POISON, NORMAL, FIGHTING, STEEL, FLYING;
  }

  public String substituir(String texto) {
    for (Tipo tipo : Tipo.values()) {
      String classe = tipo.name().toLowerCase();

      // (?i) é uma expressão regular para ignorar o case das palavras. Por exemplo: Irá encontrar Electric, ELECTRIC e electric
      // Os parênteses indicam um grupo, que será utilizado na segunda parte do replace com $ + a posição desse grupo
      // o | é uma cláusula OU na expressão regular, ou seja, irá procurar electric-type e electric também
      texto = texto.replaceAll("(?i)(" + classe + "-type|" + classe + ")", "<span class=\"tipo-pokemon " + classe + "\">$1</span>");
    }

    return texto;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pokemon pokemon = new Pokemon();

    System.out.println(pokemon.substituir("Electric-type: Quando o HP está abaixo de 1/3, os moves do tipo FIRE ganham um bônus de 50% grass."));
  }
}
```

Onde utilizo expressão regular para fazer a substituição, sem precisar percorrer o `array` de palavras.

**Na expressão regular**:

- `(?i)` é uma expressão regular para ignorar o case das palavras. Por exemplo: Irá encontrar Electric, ELECTRIC e electric;
- Os parênteses indicam um grupo, que será utilizado na segunda parte do replace com $ + a posição desse grupo;
- O `|` é uma cláusula OU na expressão regular, ou seja, irá procurar electric-type e electric também;

O código executável funcionando com a entrada abaixo pode ser verificado no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/AeRBOB)** e o `HTML` + `CSS` gerados podem ser verificados abaixo.

> Electric-type: Quando o HP está abaixo de 1/3, os moves do tipo FIRE ganham um bônus de 50% grass.

```css
span.tipo-pokemon {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}

span.tipo-pokemon.fire {
  color: #EE8130;
}

span.tipo-pokemon#water {
  color: #6890F0;
}

span.tipo-pokemon.ice {
    color: #98D8D8;
}

span.tipo-pokemon.electric {
    color: #F8D030;
}

span.tipo-pokemon.grass {
    color: #78C850;
}

span.tipo-pokemon.dark {
    color: #705848;
}

span.tipo-pokemon.bug {
    color: #A8B820;
}

span.tipo-pokemon.ghost {
    color: #705898;
}

span.tipo-pokemon.rock {
    color: #B8A038;
}

span.tipo-pokemon.fairy {
    color: #EE99AC;
}

span.tipo-pokemon.ground {
    color: #E2BF65;
}

span.tipo-pokemon.dragon {
    color: #7038F8;
}

span.tipo-pokemon.psychic {
    color: #F85888;
}

span.tipo-pokemon.poison {
    color: #A040A0;
}

span.tipo-pokemon.normal {
    color: #A8A878;
}

span.tipo-pokemon.fighting {
    color: #C03028;
}

span.tipo-pokemon.steel {
    color: #B8B8D0;
}

span.tipo-pokemon.flying {
    color: #A890F0;
}
```

```html
<span class="tipo-pokemon electric">Electric-type</span>: Quando o HP está abaixo de 1/3, os moves do tipo <span class="tipo-pokemon fire">FIRE</span> ganham um bônus de 50% <span class="tipo-pokemon grass">grass</span>.
```

Comment: Adaptei no meu código, e tirei um print pra você, vou editar na minha pergunta o resultado que saiu no dataTable.

Comment: @Douglas mas assim, com certeza isso é resultado de algum tipo híbrido que você não havia especificado, não? Qual o texto que gerou aquele problema na primeira coluna?

Comment: Sorack, adicionado na pergunta.

Comment: @Douglas não o texto gerado. O texto antes de passar pelas alterações. Pode ser aqui no comentário mesmo, mas já te adianto que tá parecendo que foi executada a função 2x para aquele texto

Comment: Sorack você brilhou cara, eu realmente estava chamando o método 2 vezes. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. :)

Comment: Algumas palavras não estão sendo capturadas :(

Comment: Retirei o . e funcionou de boas.

Comment: @Douglas Que tipo de palavras?

Comment: As que estavam no Enum, eu percebi que o caso ocorria quando elas estavam procedentes ao ponto, elas não estavam entrando na regex, eu removi o ponto da regex e agora funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: @Douglas mas ao remover o (.) você tem que remover o grupo depois também. Você fez isso?

Comment: Sim, fiz isso, obrigado.